# PostgresSQL psql shell quit doesn't return to operating system prompt but closes the terminal

Tags: postgresql, windows, psql

I am following this tutorial to learn SQL commands in PostgresSQL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hzZtqCNQKk&t=1512s&ab_channel=Amigoscode on my windows machine. The guy in the tutorial enters \q inside the SQL Shell and it exists psql and enters operating system prompt. When I try this on my computer I only get "Press any key to continue" and it closes the terminal.
Any idea why?[image]

Thank you

Comment: You are not starting `psql.exe` but some batch file, then prompts for connection information and then starts `psql.exe`. Just open a regular command line window and start `psql.exe` manually.

Answer (score 0):

for windows try ! clr and make sure to space before clr.